# Are most semigroups nilpotent of degree 3?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, enumerative-combinatorics

A semigroup is **nilpotent of degree 3** if every product of 3 elements gives the same result.  In 2012, [Andreas Distler and James D. Mitchell](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.3529) wrote that:

> It is part of the folklore of semigroup theory that almost all finite semigroups are nilpotent of degree 3.

Here's a way to make this precise:

**Conjecture.** If $S(n)$ is the number of isomorphism classes of semigroups with $n$ elements, and $S_3(n)$ is the number of isomorphism classes of semigroups with $n$ elements that are nilpotent of degree 3, then

$$  \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{S_3(n)}{S(n)} = 1. $$

**Has anyone proved this, or a similar result?**

Semigroup theorists seem to enjoy counting semigroups up to **equivalence**, meaning up to isomorphism or anti-isomorphism, so maybe someone has proved a similar result but counting semigroups up to equivalence rather than up to isomomorphism.

In 2012, [Andreas Distler, Chris Jefferson, Tom Kelsey, and Lars Kottho](https://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~larsko/papers/distler_semigroups_2012.pdf) counted the semigroups with 10 elements and found

$$ 12,418,001,077,381,302,684  $$

of them.   Of these, all but

$$ 718,981,858,383,872 $$

were nilpotent of degree 3.  So, about 99.994% were nilpotent of degree 3.

By the way, this calculation still took [a lot of work](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2020/04/14/bigness-part-3/).

Comment: I believe if you count labeled multiplication tables rather than isomorphism then the result is known.  See https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-055-01/S0002-9939-1976-0414380-0/S0002-9939-1976-0414380-0.pdf for labeled semigroups.

Comment: Since 3-nilpotent is anti-isomorphism-invariant and passing from isomorphism classes to equivalence classes is $\le 2$-to-1, counting up to isomorphism or equivalence doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry. I deleted too many old comments. I'll rewrite. Nobody has ever proved this folklore conjecture. It is like the conjecture that almost all finite groups of order less than n are 2-groups. Everybody believes it but no ideas how to prove it.

Comment: For isomorphism classes, it is not even known how many there are semigroups of order $n$, $n>20$. So 99% for all $n$ seems unrealistic to prove. Something like $>50\%$ seems possible but it is not obvious. But, yes, I do not know any semigroup theorist who does not believe 99.9% (in fact $\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$ and the convergence is more than exponentially fast).

Comment: Of course, there are also finite semilattices of height 3. Their number is large.  I wonder if anybody has computed the number. They are somewhat similar to 3-nilp semigroups.

Comment: A lower bound for the number of semilattices of height 3 and order n is computed in our 1994 paper with Ed Scheinerman  "Irrepresentability of short semilattices by euclidean subspaces".